# Prevent elasticsearch from being killed by OOM killer

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and I'm guessing the way I configured my server is sub-optimal since I'm running into a problem with OOM killer killing the Elasticsearch/Java process after a short while.This could probably be avoided by having the server configured correctly. Could you please point out what in the configuration needs to be changed for a smooth operation of ES?

On both of these servers (which are clustered), I sometimes come back to the ES/java process having been killed.

Here is the current setup:

===========================================

Server 1 (Frontend server)
This server has 8GB of RAM and is also running gunicorn, Flask, and Django

elasticsearch.yml:

```
node.master: true
node.data: true
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

/etc/default/elasticsearch

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=5g
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
```

===========================================

Server 2 (Dedicated Elasticsearch server) with 8GB RAM and no other applications running

elasticsearch.yml:

```
node.master: false
node.data: true
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

/etc/default/elasticsearch

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=5g
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
```

===========================================

In the elasticsearch.yml file, I see a line that says "`You should also make sure that the Elasticsearch process is allowed to lock the memory, eg. by using ulimit -l unlimited`"
But I haven't done anything to enable that. Do I need to take any action here?

If I try typing that in, I get...

```
myuser@es1:~$ sudo ulimit -l unlimited
sudo: ulimit: command not found
```

Comment: If you feel something is wrong with this question, please provide constructive comments so it can be improved, rather than anonymously downvoting it.

Answer (score 15):

Here is what I have done to lock the memory on my ES nodes, version 5.4.0 on RedHat/Centos 7 (it will work on other distributions if they use **systemd**).

You must make the change in 4 different places:

1) **/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch**

On sysconfig: `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` you should have:

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g" 
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
```

(replace 4g with HALF your available RAM as recommended [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html))

2) **/etc/security/limits.conf**

On security limits config: `/etc/security/limits.conf` you should have

```
elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
```

3) **/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service**

On the service script: `/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service` you should uncomment:

```
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

you should do systemctl daemon-reload after changing the service script

4) **/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml**

On elasticsearch config finally: `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` you should add:

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
```

Thats it, restart your node and the RAM will be locked, you should notice a major performance improvement.

Comment: I am having almost the exact same issue as OP.  See my post here: [ES Server shuts down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469742/elasticserver-shuts-down-at-random-times-throughout-the-day/45476584?noredirect=1#comment77984101_45476584).  I have gone through your config changes and the server still shuts down.  The dmesg output states that OOM is killing java.  If upon completing all your suggested config changes OOM still kills java, is it safe to say the fix is a memory upgrade to the host?

Comment: Upgrading RAM to 8 GB solved the OOM-KILL issue for me. However, I have applied the recommended settings in the above answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

So there's not a lot you can do config-wise to prevent the OOM killer from being invoked but I will walk you thru what you can do. To recap, the OOM killer is invoked when Linux believes it is low on memory and needs to free up memory. It's going to pick longer running, high memory processes in general which makes Elasticsearch a prime target.

Things you can try:

1. Move any other production code to another system. At least on the
   front end system with 8GB of memory running ES with 5GB of heap,
   Django and Flask can stress your memory usage. It's generally a
   better idea to run ES data nodes on their own hardware or instance.
2. Cut the heap size. Elasticsearch recommends using no more than half
   of memory for heap, so I'd cut it down to 4GB or less. You should
   then be monitoring heap usage closely and continue to ratchet it
   down while you still have a decent margin.
3. Upgrade to a larger server with more memory. This would be my number
   one recommendation - you simply don't have enough memory available
   to do everything you are trying to do on one server.
4. Try tuning the OOM killer to be less strict - not that easy to do
   and I don't know what you will gain due to overall low server size
   but you can always experiment:

   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58872/how-to-set-oom-killer-adjustments-for-daemons-permanently

   http://backdrift.org/how-to-create-oom-killer-exceptions

   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed recommendations! I'll give all of those a try.

Comment: I've tried the recommendations above, but something weird is happening: either one or both of the server goes down when I'm indexing documents. After 10k-20k documents, the indexing hangs and at least one of the servers is down. Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: depending upon linux version I'd be looking in /var/log/syslog for OOM kills or other memory errors plus wherever your Elasticsearch installations are logging -