# ElasticServer shuts down at random times throughout the day

Tags: java, elasticsearch, centos

For the past few weeks, we have been having an issue where the ElasticSearch server dies.  I cannot tell what the problem is and I'm not really sure where to even start?

We can restart the server and it will run ok for random lengths of time.  Sometimes for the rest of the day, sometimes minutes, but it always crashes again eventually.

Here are some details that I hope someone will be able to process and point me in the right direction:

ElasticSearch Server info:

```
{
  "name" : "WIuGVV9",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "T2Vvt3hzQhSJa4ZFWtdMKA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.1",
    "build_hash" : "19c13d0",
    "build_date" : "2017-07-18T20:44:24.823Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

$ cat /etc/centos-release

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

$ java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b16, mixed mode)
```

$ free

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7915072     3650556     2827472      378156     1437044     3802152
Swap:             0           0           0
```

elasticsearch.log:

```
[2017-08-02T14:14:37,927][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna3117985363123958860.tmp: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna3117985363123958860.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:947) ~[jna-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:922) ~[jna-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:190) ~[jna-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0 (b0)]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:105) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:194) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:351) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) [elasticsearch-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
[2017-08-02T14:14:37,936][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2017-08-02T14:14:37,937][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot install system call filter because JNA is not available
[2017-08-02T14:14:37,937][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2017-08-02T14:14:37,941][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_NPROC because JNA is not available
[2017-08-02T14:14:37,941][WARN ][o.e.b.Natives            ] cannot getrlimit RLIMIT_AS beacuse JNA is not available
[2017-08-02T14:14:38,150][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2017-08-02T14:14:38,341][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [WIuGVV9] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [7.8gb], net total_space [38.7gb], spins? [unknown], types [rootfs]
[2017-08-02T14:14:38,341][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [WIuGVV9] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-08-02T14:14:38,452][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [WIuGVV9] derived from node ID [WIuGVV9sS0mlLPTxRVKn0w]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-08-02T14:14:38,453][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.5.1], pid[21555], build[19c13d0/2017-07-18T20:44:24.823Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_141/25.141-b16]
[2017-08-02T14:14:38,453][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] JVM arguments [-Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,409][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [parent-join]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-08-02T14:14:40,411][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [WIuGVV9] no plugins loaded
[2017-08-02T14:14:42,797][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [WIuGVV9] using discovery type [zen]
[2017-08-02T14:14:43,759][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-08-02T14:14:43,760][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WIuGVV9] starting ...
[2017-08-02T14:14:44,061][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [WIuGVV9] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2017-08-02T14:14:44,088][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [WIuGVV9] system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
[2017-08-02T14:14:47,174][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [WIuGVV9] new_master {WIuGVV9}{WIuGVV9sS0mlLPTxRVKn0w}{uZIN-61JT4KLP1xUSVTdLQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-08-02T14:14:47,204][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [WIuGVV9] publish_address {66.55.80.152:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2017-08-02T14:14:47,204][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [WIuGVV9] started
[2017-08-02T14:14:47,589][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [WIuGVV9] recovered [3] indices into cluster_state
[2017-08-02T14:14:48,268][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [WIuGVV9] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[orgs][4], [orgs][0]] ...]).
[2017-08-02T14:18:01,316][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [WIuGVV9] [orgs/ZcizOIAsRWqSXZY8ZiR0BA] deleting index
```

/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
#network.bind_host: "0.0.0.0"
#network.publish_host: _non_loopback:ipv4_
#network.host: _local_
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#network.bind_host: 
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options :

```
## JVM configuration

################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## You should always set the min and max JVM heap
## size to the same value. For example, to set
## the heap to 4 GB, set:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################

# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms2g
-Xmx2g

################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below this section are considered
## expert settings. Don't tamper with them unless
## you understand what you are doing
##
################################################################

## GC configuration
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly

## optimizations

# pre-touch memory pages used by the JVM during initialization
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

## basic

# force the server VM (remove on 32-bit client JVMs)
-server

# explicitly set the stack size (reduce to 320k on 32-bit client JVMs)
-Xss1m

# set to headless, just in case
-Djava.awt.headless=true

# ensure UTF-8 encoding by default (e.g. filenames)
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# use our provided JNA always versus the system one
-Djna.nosys=true

# use old-style file permissions on JDK9
-Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true

# flags to configure Netty
-Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true
-Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true
-Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0

# log4j 2
-Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false
-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true
-Dlog4j.skipJansi=true

## heap dumps

# generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails
# heap dumps are created in the working directory of the JVM
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# specify an alternative path for heap dumps
# ensure the directory exists and has sufficient space
#-XX:HeapDumpPath=${heap.dump.path}

## GC logging

#-XX:+PrintGCDetails
#-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
#-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
#-XX:+PrintClassHistogram
#-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
#-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime

# log GC status to a file with time stamps
# ensure the directory exists
#-Xloggc:${loggc}

# By default, the GC log file will not rotate.
# By uncommenting the lines below, the GC log file
# will be rotated every 128MB at most 32 times.
#-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
#-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32
#-XX:GCLogFileSize=128M

# Elasticsearch 5.0.0 will throw an exception on unquoted field names in JSON.
# If documents were already indexed with unquoted fields in a previous version
# of Elasticsearch, some operations may throw errors.
#
# WARNING: This option will be removed in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 and is provided
# only for migration purposes.
#-Delasticsearch.json.allow_unquoted_field_names=true
```

/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch :

```
################################
# Elasticsearch
################################

# Elasticsearch home directory
#ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch Java path
#JAVA_HOME=

# Elasticsearch configuration directory
#CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch data directory
#DATA_DIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch logs directory
#LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch PID directory
#PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch

# Additional Java OPTS
#ES_JAVA_OPTS=

# Configure restart on package upgrade (true, every other setting will lead to not restarting)
#RESTART_ON_UPGRADE=true

################################
# Elasticsearch service
################################

# SysV init.d
#
# When executing the init script, this user will be used to run the elasticsearch service.
# The default value is 'elasticsearch' and is declared in the init.d file.
# Note that this setting is only used by the init script. If changed, make sure that
# the configured user can read and write into the data, work, plugins and log directories.
# For systemd service, the user is usually configured in file /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
#ES_USER=elasticsearch
#ES_GROUP=elasticsearch

# The number of seconds to wait before checking if Elasticsearch started successfully as a daemon process
ES_STARTUP_SLEEP_TIME=5

################################
# System properties
################################

# Specifies the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process
# When using Systemd, this setting is ignored and the LimitNOFILE defined in
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service takes precedence
#MAX_OPEN_FILES=65536

# The maximum number of bytes of memory that may be locked into RAM
# Set to "unlimited" if you use the 'bootstrap.memory_lock: true' option
# in elasticsearch.yml.
# When using Systemd, the LimitMEMLOCK property must be set
# in /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
#MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited

# Maximum number of VMA (Virtual Memory Areas) a process can own
# When using Systemd, this setting is ignored and the 'vm.max_map_count'
# property is set at boot time in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/elasticsearch.conf
#MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144
```

Can anyone determine what my error is?  I can't tell and my best best is either a permissions issue, or a memory issue.  We do have 8 gb, which is the barely make it mark.

Thoughts?

Thanks a million.

[EDIT: New Details] :

dmesg outputs a lot.  I'm not sure if there is a way to get timestamps out of the output, but over and over I see:

```
[10131180.901171] Out of memory: Kill process 13777 (java) score 295 or sacrifice child
[10131180.901186] Killed process 13777 (java) total-vm:5800372kB, anon-rss:2334928kB, file-rss:80kB
[10137088.438235] exim[7581]: segfault at 58 ip 000000000046bee7 sp 00007ffdd0dc63e0 error 4 in exim[400000+fa000]
[10138765.544389] exim[16401]: segfault at 58 ip 000000000046bee7 sp 00007ffede7cc3f0 error 4 in exim[400000+fa000]
[10162265.107101] exim[28217]: segfault at 58 ip 000000000046bee7 sp 00007fff84afb6e0 error 4 in exim[400000+fa000]
```

I think this is the root cause of our issue and when the boss gets in we will see about upgrading the server as it only has 8gb of ram.

[EDIT: even newer details] :

Running this command:

```
ps -eo pmem,pcpu,vsize,pid,cmd | sort -k 1 -nr | head -5
```

After the ES server is killed:

```
6.3  0.0 767376   560 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/clamd
2.7 25.5 310612  5060 dovecot/lmtp
2.4  0.3 860920 24850 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/gigenet.pwi.com.err --open-files-limit=10000 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/gigenet.pwi.com.pid
0.3  0.3  75216 17701 tailwatchd
0.3  0.0 393280  5384 /usr/sbin/named -u named
```

After the ES server is restarted

```
9.3 45.5 4834304 6815 /bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms4g -Xmx4g -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid --quiet -Edefault.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Edefault.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Edefault.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
6.3  0.0 767376   560 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/clamd
2.4  0.3 860920 24850 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/gigenet.pwi.com.err --open-files-limit=10000 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/gigenet.pwi.com.pid
1.2  1.1 243444 23536 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/524/bin/perl -T -w /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/spamd --max-spare=1 --max-children=3 --allowed-ips=127.0.0.1,::1 --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid --listen=5 --listen=6
1.2  0.5 244292  6618 spamd child
```

Based on the results in the answers to the question, I found this post

[Prevent elasticsearch from being killed by OOM killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355726/prevent-elasticsearch-from-being-killed-by-oom-killer)

While trying to figure out why OOM is killing java.  I have since changed my config to match the recommendations in the first answer and the server still shuts down.

based on dmesg, the processes being killed are:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 24532 (java) score 293
Out of memory: Kill process 3408 (clamd) score 60
Out of memory: Kill process 1970 (lmtp) score 28
Out of memory: Kill process 17806 (mysqld) score 27
```

Comment: is your /tmp/ directory with noexec mounted? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18406

Comment: I saw that post, which is where I got most of the commands to output the above.  Here is the output:

cat /proc/mounts | grep /tmp
/dev/loop0 /tmp ext3 rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/loop0 /var/tmp ext3 rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,data=ordered 0 0

Comment: I ruled that post out as it seemed he couldn't get the server to start at all where I can start it no issue and later it will die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there anything in the logs of Elasticsearch that indicates are clean shutdown? Can you paste the lines **before** the restart?

Can you check with `dmesg` if the kernel OOM killer is stopping elasticsearch? This happens when the operating system is advised to free memory at all cost. The OOM killer then usually picks the process with the most memory and kills it. Most of the time this is Elasticsearch.

Are there any other services running on that machine, that might cause triggering the OOM killer?

Have you monitoring the system over time? Is memory eaten up? If the process is killed, are certain resources back to normal?

Comment: I made an edit to the post to include a small bit of the dmesg output.  Seems pretty clear that the system is running out of memory and killing java.  It has the Out of memory, closing Java message over and over.  I can't upgrade the server, when the one who can gets in we will look into it and if it fixes the issue I'll mark this as the solution, else I'll post more details including more of the elasticsearch log.  Thanks!

Comment: the main question is, why is it running out of memory. Unless Elasticsearch has a bug, then you should configure its heap, it needs a certain amount of native memory outside of the JVM and that's. so it's important to find the offending process that eats more memory over time.

Comment: Every time the ES server goes down, which is a few times a day, the dmesg output is updated with "Out of memory: Kill process 13777 (java)."  8gb of ram and there are other services running off that server.  Furthermore, recently we had someone in there doing some work so they may have added something that pushed the available ram down.  This issue did start about that time, and wasn't an issue before.  We are looking into upgrading the ram and the Host isn't making it very clear.  I am marking your answer as the correct one as dmesg did point me in what I think is the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure (and make my above point more clear), the OOM killer only kills the process that needs most memory, but this might not be the offending process that eats all your memory. Killing the ES process is a symptom here, but maybe not the cause.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.  Based on what I have found, I'm fairly confident that a server upgrade is in order but need to be 100% sure of this.  What other recommendations can you make to insure that it is in fact ES(java) causing the problem and not some other service?  Thanks again for baring with me on this.